# I am using Actions class to move to an element but I am unable to click the elements in the dropdown

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, action

```
public static void main() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        Actions a = new Actions(driver);
        WebElement as = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='yourAccount']"));
        a.moveToElement(as).build().perform();
        WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='hFlyout guest gnf_nav_depth2_list']//li[12]//button"));
        System.out.println(login.isDisplayed());
        login.click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.switchTo().frame(1);
        System.out.println("pass");
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Join for free")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
}
```

- Website : http://www.sears.com/
- Mouse over element : Sign in Account&points
- Dropdown element: "Join for free"
- I am using Firefox browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `Thread.sleep()` as it's a bad practice. Use `WebDriverWait` instead.

From your code, it looks like your hover is correct but you need a brief wait to make sure that the panel opens and the "Join for free" button is visible and clickable. A `WebDriverWait` takes care of this easily... you just wait for the button to be clickable and then click it.

```
driver.get("https://www.sears.com/");
Actions hover = new Actions(driver);
hover.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("yourAccount"))).build().perform();
new WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button[data-action='join']"))).click();
```

This code works for me.